# Alias 2.32 module fails to buid in Perl 5.36.1 on macOS

Tags: perl, compilation, alias

The Alias 2.32 module is very old but still useful, if it can be made to work. Building it in a perlbrew Perl 5.36.1 produces two compiler errors, to wit:

Alias.xs:208:4: error: cannot take the address of an rvalue of type 'CV *' (aka 'struct cv *')
SAVESPTR(GvCV(gv));

and;

Alias.xs:209:13: error: expression is not assignable
GvCV(gv) = Null(CV*);

These expressions appear in Alias.xs in a switch statement as:

```
                switch (stype) {
                case SVt_PVAV:
                    save_ary(gv);
                    break;
                case SVt_PVHV:
                    save_hash(gv);
                    break;
                case SVt_PVGV:
                    save_gp(gv,TRUE);   /* hide previous entry in symtab */
                    break;
                case SVt_PVCV:
                    SAVESPTR(GvCV(gv));
                    GvCV(gv) = Null(CV*);
                    break;
```

This module must have been buildable at some point but newer Perls may have deprecated those constructions. Any ideas how to fix these errors?

Thanks for assistance.

Comment: https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=64987

Comment: Note the presence of alternatives: Data::Alias, and even the built-in still-experimental-although-I-expect-it-to-be-accepted [`refaliasing` feature](https://metacpan.org/pod/feature#The-'refaliasing'-feature).

Comment: Thank you ikegami. Just what I wanted. It looks like the maintainer of the Alias module ignored the deprecation announcement.  Also, the maintainer of Data::Alias advises to use the core feature, now that it is available.